# Equivalence of the $H^1$ norm and the energy entropy norm

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, fluid-dynamics

Let $D \subset \mathbb R^2$ be a bounded domain with smooth boundary. Let $\mathbf v: D \to \mathbb R^2$ be a divergence free vector field tangent to the boundary, i.e., $\mbox{ div } \mathbf v = 0$ in $D$ and $\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf n = 0$ on the boundary of $D$, where $\mathbf n$ is the unit normal vector on the boundary. 
How does one show that the $H^1$ norm of $\mathbf v$, given by, $||\mathbf v||_2+ ||\nabla \mathbf  v||_2 $ is equivalent to $||\mathbf v||_2+ ||\mbox{ curl }\mathbf v||_2$. Here $||\cdot||_2$ represents the $L^2$ norm. (The latter sum is sometimes called the energy and entropy norm.)

Comment: You need the "Biot-Savart law."  I'm not sure enough about the details to give a full answer.

Comment: @ mathematician Thanks for the pointer. Will check it out.

Comment: I think the way you want to do it is extend $v$ by 0 to $\mathbb{R}^2$, then the map from curl $v$ to $\nabla v$ is a Calderon-Zygmund operator, which is bounded in $L^2$.